# 'overflow-x: hidden' isn't working on a single element?

Tags: html, css, overflow

currently working on programming my own website for my music. Everything has been going smoothly, but this one thing is just not working for me. one of my divs is not being hidden by the overflow rule.

The element has a position value of absolute and is almost an exact replica of another div that is behaving normally. The only difference is that one is translated off the screen to right and the other to the left. The left one is the one that refuses to be hidden.

I haven't been able to see why. I've changed various things around and still no luck. The only time I got close was when I changed the direct parent of the element from static to relative, but it moved all my items down and cut them at a certain point. I messed around with the CSS but could not bring them up at all.

I uploaded the entire code here as I don't know what all you need to look at:
https://github.com/OfficialXammaX/Official-LOVE-Website#official-love-website